# how to send dynamic PDF with mail() those generate by DOMPDF library in CI?

Tags: codeigniter

Actually, generate the dynamic PDF successfully with the help of dompdf library in CI but not send the pdf dynamic those generated here. So tell me how to do this?

```
  $filename = "newpdffile";
    require_once APPPATH.'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();


    $dompdf->loadHtml($output);
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream($filename);

    $file_to_save="/application/dompdf/";
    $pdf=file_put_contents($file_to_save, $dompdf->output());

     $this->email->from('support@aurorax.co', 'aurora exchange');
        $this->email->to('masnad@aurorax.co');
        $this->email->subject('pdf');
        $this->email->attach($pdf);
        $this->email->message('Hello!');
```

Comment: Do you want send PDF file in email?

Comment: yes i want to send pdf

Comment: pls anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code:

```
$filename = "newpdffile";
    require_once APPPATH.'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();


    $dompdf->loadHtml($output);
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
    $dompdf->render();


    $output = $dompdf->output();
    $filePath = FCPATH.'application/dompdf/filename.pdf';
    file_put_contents($filePath, $output);

    $this->email->from('support@aurorax.co', 'aurora exchange');
        $this->email->to('masnad@aurorax.co');
        $this->email->subject('pdf');
        $this->email->attach($filePath);
        $this->email->message('Hello!');
```

Comment: It's `FCPATH` not `FC_PATH`

Comment: its code is not work here.. error show Failed to load PDF document.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sucesssfully generated PDF and saved in dompfdf directory
then

```
$pdf= 'http://yourwebsite.com/dompfdf/<?php echo $pdfNameYouGenerated; ?>';
$this->email->attach($pdf);
```

Comment: file is not save firstly

Comment: @PRATIKSHAGOYAL so you are not able to generate PDF, right?

Comment: i generate the PDF succesfully  but i not able to save pdf in particular folder

Answer (score 0):

Use `APPPATH` to get the file path

```
$file_to_save = APPPATH. "application/dompdf/";
$pdf = file_put_contents($file_to_save, $dompdf->output());
```

When PDF file successfully generated and save in the directory then attach while sending email

```
$this->email->from('support@aurorax.co', 'aurora exchange');
$this->email->to('masnad@aurorax.co');
$this->email->subject('pdf');
$this->email->attach($pdf);
$this->email->message('Hello!');
```

Comment: what to do? pls suggest me

Comment: But according to your question file is saving in folder `dompdf` inside the application folder

Comment: i tired to save the PDF file  after generate that time show the Failed to load PDF document... so what to do ???

Comment: file is not saving in folder dompdf inside the application folder @danish ali

Comment: Refer to this link https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Using-Dompdf-in-CodeIgniter-3.x